# Replace inner HTML of a div with Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i am trying to change inner HTML of a div after some interval. 
i am getting right response which i want with Ajax. 
but unable to replace inner HTML of selected after and with Ajax response.
what is wrong with my code..

**Html**

```
      <p class="time ui-li-desc" data-time="2013-02-13 11:30:08" >
    51 seconds ago<img alt="image" src="images/read.png"></p>

      <p class="time ui-li-desc" data-time="2013-02-13 11:30:16" >
    58 seconds ago<img alt="image" src="images/read.png"></p>
.
.
.
.
.
      <p class="time ui-li-desc" data-time="2013-02-13 11:40:08" >
    10 minute ago<img alt="image" src="images/read.png"></p>
```

**j query**

```
setInterval(function() { 
            $( ".time" ).each(function( index ) {
                var sendTime=  $(this).attr("data-time");
                dataString = "sendtime="+sendTime+"&q=convertTime";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "data_handler.php",
                    data: dataString,                   
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                        $(this).html(response);
                        //alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` is the window in the callback. Use the value given to the `callback` of each :

```
        $( ".time" ).each(function(index , elem) {
            var sendTime=  $(this).attr("data-time");
            dataString = "sendtime="+sendTime+"&q=convertTime";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "data_handler.php",
                data: dataString,                   
                cache: true,
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                    $(elem).html(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

You *don't* need to define a new variable to protect `this` as jQuery already does it for you.

Answer (score 5):

As you are using an asynchronous function with a callback, `this` in your callback doesn't come from the same context. You need to save `this` in a variable used in the callback.

Try like this:

```
setInterval(function() { 
            $( ".time" ).each(function( index ) {
                var sendTime=  $(this).attr("data-time");
                dataString = "sendtime="+sendTime+"&q=convertTime";
                var self = this;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "data_handler.php",
                    data: dataString,                   
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                        $(self).html(response);
                        //alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        }, 5000);
```

Comment: This adds useless code : jQuery declares a variable already... See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think $(this) is out of context. Try:

```
setInterval(function() { 
            $( ".time" ).each(function( index ) {
                var $this = $(this);
                var sendTime=  $(this).attr("data-time");
                dataString = "sendtime="+sendTime+"&q=convertTime";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "data_handler.php",
                    data: dataString,                   
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response);
                        $this.html(response);
                        //alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() { 
        $( ".time" ).each(function( index ) {
            var sendTime=  $(this).attr("data-time");
            var _thisvariable = $(this);
            dataString = "sendtime="+sendTime+"&q=convertTime";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "data_handler.php",
                data: dataString,                   
                cache: true,
                success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                    _thisvariable.html(response);
                    //alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    }, 5000);
```