# How to include a jsp inside another jsp using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I have a button logout. Once logout is clicked I need to show another page. How can I do this using JavaScript? Can anyone please help me?

My Code:

```
<s:form name="LogoutAction"
                id="LogoutAction" action="logout">
    <span class="inlayField2">
    <s:a href="logout" cssClass="planTabHeader" id="logoutId"> <img src="../../KY/images/common/header/lock.png" alt="logout" style="border: none;background-color: transparent;" /> &nbsp;Log out</s:a></span>
    </s:form>
```

I tried this:

```
$('#logoutId').click(function(event) {

    $('#logoutdiv').load('ConfirmationPopup.jsp');
});
```

Comment: so, did you face any error?

Comment: no.I am not getting any error.The page is not getting loaded

Comment: try checking in javascript console.

Comment: how about  /ConfirmationPopup.jsp ??

Comment: @Baadshah : I tried that also.but no use.

Comment: Do you need to include or redirect to that page?

Comment: I need to include that page

Answer (score 3):

You can't `include` a JSP in respone to a click on the client side because it's a server-side technology. You could include the desired HTML in the page before it's sent, hide that area with CSS, and then make it visible in response to a mouse click using JavaScript.The `include` would already have happened on the server before the page was sent to the client. You can have something like this:

```
<div id="confirmPopup" style="display:hidden;">
      <%@ include file="ConfirmationPopup.jsp" %>
</div>
<script>
  $('#logoutId').click(function(event) {
   document.getElementById("confirmPopup").style.display="block";
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have a problem here...I am getting the confirmationpopup.jsp everytime when I load the page which which is containing the logout.It is not showing up when the logout is clicked.

Comment: Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use ajax to get the html from the 2nd jsp and then append to the DOM or to the innerHTML of a element.

**Main Page.jsp**

```
<span id=confirmSpan></span>
<script language="Javascript">
function xmlhttpPost(strURL, queryStr) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari, opera etc
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
        alert("no ajax")
        return
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepageConfirm(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(queryStr);
}


function updatepageConfirm(str){
    document.getElementById("confirmSpan").innerHTML = str;
}
function logout1(){
xmlhttpPost("confirm.html");//http://sel2in.com/pages/prog/html/ajax/confirm.html", "")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form  id="search" action="/search" method="get">
<input type=button onclick=logout1() value=logout>
</form >
```

Sample page with confirm code -> any valid html for the div could be 
**confirm.jsp**
Do action ... Are you sure?

//todo form here
html of span/ pop up/ script/ css -> just like an iframe

Looks like you want to show a confirmation - some UI asking do you really want to logout?

Best way for that would be to make an empty span with id "logoutConfirmSpan" then on click of logout, do the ajax (async mode -> false so it happens inline) get the html markup and set it to the innerHTML of the span

The html should be valid such that it makes the UI appear and the form to really logout.

See [Replace inner HTML of a div with Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851684/replace-inner-html-of-a-div-with-ajax-response) tells you how to use ajax with jQuery

Simple sample:

[HTML snippets](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/12/the_ajax_respon.html)

```
<span id = 'logoutConfirmSpan'> </span>
<script>
// call ajax, with the response call setHtmlForConfirm
function setHtmlForConfirm(req)
{
    document.getElementById('logoutConfirmSpan').innerHTML = req.responseText;
}
//req.responseText should have the html to show the confirm UI and form to submit yes/ no
</script>
```

Comment: could you be a bit more clear or could you please show me some example since I dont have any experience with ajax

Comment: suggest you go thru the stacktrace http://stackoverflow.com/a/14851734/1643558 you are asking the same thing- see the answer there. if you want some background on ajax see http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/12/the_ajax_respon.html search for "HTML snippets"

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without using ajax?

Comment: but wat is req.responseText

Comment: go thru http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/12/the_ajax_respon.html it has all the code Or see http://sel2in.com/pages/prog/html/ajax/aPage.html -->  updatepageConfirm(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `GET` request to fetch the HTML rendered by the secondary `.jsp` page.
Basically, from within Ajax, with jQuery you can do:

```
$.get({
    url: "mysite.com/otherpage.jsp",
    data: "some data you want to send, optional",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXhr)//the response data, the ajax request status and the ajax request object itself {
        $('#someDiv').html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Create a `<div id='someID'></div>` while initial page load
>
> 2) on button click, thru javascript create an iframe with your new jsp
>   url
>
> 3) Once the iframe content loaded show it as a popup perhaps in dialog
>   window

Comment: I have never used iframes and all. Could you please explain a bit more or show me some example?

Comment: I dont need iframes...I have a page already...I need to show that page using javascript...How can I do that...because we are using same format of confirmation messages everywhere and I dont need to change it

Comment: Yea it did that...but in that case, I got the popup whenever the page is loaded and not when the logout is clicked.

Comment: Put this block  $('#logoutId').click(function(event) {
   document.getElementById("confirmPopup").style.display="block";
  }); inside a function and call that function when logout is clicked

Comment: I tried this :      ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
    ifrm.setAttribute("src", "/WebContent/planmanagement/planSummary/ConfirmationPopup.jsp"); 
    ifrm.style.width = 640+"px"; 
    ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
    document.getElementById("confirmPopup").innerHTML = ifrm;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28726/discussion-between-mukund-and-madhu)

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it to keep a span and on click do:
http://sel2in.com/pages/prog/html/ajax/aPage2.html1

```
<span id=confirmSpan></span>
<script language="Javascript">

function logout1(){
    iconfirmSpan = document.getElementById("confirmSpan")
    if (!confirmSpan){
        alert("Error no confirmSpan contact support!");
    }
    confirmSpan.innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"http://sel2in.com/pages/prog/html/ajax/confirm.html\" height=400 width=700></iframe>"
    //in real can keep height 1 width 1 and location off page if you want it just to load elements, scripts etc
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form  id="search" action="/search" method="get">
<input type=button onclick=logout1() value="Do Action">
</form >
```

Comment: but ajax is more powerful for workflows and such, but this might be enough if only 1 action

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is what you are looking for.

I strongly suggest you to perform `AJAX` calls with **`jQuery`** ([showcase -> div](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)) , but in `Struts2` you can try with the *deprecated* `Dojo` plugin in a second, without the need to download any library, just to make you an idea.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s"  uri="/struts-tags"      %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags" %>

<head>      
    <sx:head/>
    <script>
       function loadAjax(){
           var div = dojo.widget.byId("myDiv");
           div.href = "yourAjaxAction.action";
           div.refresh();
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" 
           value="Include a JSP fragment dynamically" 
           onclick="loadAjax();"/>

    <sx:div id="myDiv"> </sx:div>

</body>
```

And then, your `yourAjaxAction.action` must return on SUCCESS the JSP snippet you want to include.