# How to use s:if to compare the value of s:hidden

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I have s: hidden tag like this...

```
<s:hidden name="hiddenpopup" value="0" id="hiddenpopup"/>
```

I am setting the value of the hiddenpopup in javascript like this :

```
document.getElementById("hiddenpopup").value=5;
```

Now I want to compare the value of this in jsp and I am doing like this :

```
<s:if test="%{#hiddenpopup==5}">
    <%@ include file="/planmanagement/planSummary/ConfirmationPopup.jsp" %>
    </s:if>
```

Is this way of comparing right or Where am I going wrong? Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a jsp inside another jsp using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162450/how-to-include-a-jsp-inside-another-jsp-using-javascript)

Comment: possibly you didn't set a variable referencing a value of the hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

JSP tags are processed on the server and is rendered as HTML in the browser before any javascript is executed. So what you try to do is not possible. If you change the value of the input field with javascript, you have to also do your check with javascript, or perform a post back to the server.

Comment: In JavaScript: if(document.getElementById("hiddenpopup").value === 5) {// Do your stuff }

Comment: Actually what I am  asking is whether it is possible to include a page using javascript

Comment: No, not like that. All JSP directives are processed on the server and has completed before any javascript is executed. You have to do a post back to your server in that case (maybe you're doing it already. It's not really clear from your question).

Comment: I need to include a page based on the comparison. So how it can be done?

Comment: Is there any way of showing a page using javascript like window.load or something like that?

Comment: Are you doing a post in between the JSP pages? If you do, your code seems correct, given you have an object in the value stack that has a `hiddenpopup` property.

Answer (score 0):

you will not get it the s:if will be executed on page load but ur function that sets the value will work only after that